# Jquery click bind doesn't work second time

Tags: jquery, click, bind, href

i have a strange behaviour with `a` and with `img` tag inside.

I have a php page with a table that is a list of records.
At the end of every row i have a button for delete row.

This is the code of my table:

```
<div class='edit' >
    <a id='20' href='#' return;>
        <img src='images/edit.png'  />
    </a>
</div>
```

Every record, every row of the main table, has the code above, with different id each other.

My script code is:

```
$("#delete a").click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

$('#action').val("delete");
$('#keyAction').val(this.id);

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "processAttivita.php",
        data: $("#attivita_form").serialize(),
        error: function(msg) {
            $("#errore").html(msg);
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            // display the errors returned by server side validation (if any)
            ricaricaLista();                

        }
    });     

 // end click delete event  
 });
```

The first row i try to delete clicking on the image works fine.
On the second one it seems that jquery doesn't bind "click" event and default href of `a` element occurs, remaining on the same page due the "#" in href attribute.

Any ideas why the second time jquery doesn't intercept click on `<a>` element ?

Comment: Are you adding the rows dynamically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using an ID selector `#delete a` which will only match one (generally the first) element.

Try using a class, e.g. `.delete a`.

The reason you only get one element is because JQuery optimizes any selector that begins with `#` passes through to `document.getElementById`, which only returns 1 element.

Here's an example of how to use event delegation to achieve the same thing:

```
$("#tableid").click(".delete a", function(e) {
    // your code
});
```

Your html would need to have an ID on your table and give `class="delete"` to the container of your delete links.

Comment: Maybe even `.edit`? There's no element with id or class `delete` in the OP's given html.

Comment: @AustinMullins I assume from "At the end of every row i have a button for delete row" that there is a div, td, or something else there with `id="delete"` on every row, containing a link or something like `<a>delete</a>`.

Comment: Even better would be to use event-delegation, especially when showing a LONG list of rows, which will cause at least *two* event-handlers to be attached per row. So, something like: `$(document).on('click', 'a.edit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); .....});` This will capture ALL edit-buttons in one line, and even works when replacing the table via ajax (e.g. paginating)

Comment: @thaJeztah You bet. Probably a bridge too far for the OP's immediate needs though.

Comment: @Plynx You could append it to your answer as an example. Trying to educate people one-at-a-time. I'm surprised by the amount of 'experienced' developers *not* being aware of what the impact of a simple $('a').click() is!

Comment: thank you guys !! I'm novice with JQuery and simple problem are for me high mountains...
 the right solution was "$(document).on('click', 'a.edit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); .....});" because i create dinamically new row.

Comment: @fabribs Great job! Glad you got it working. You can also substitute something like `#tableid` for `document` (either way works, it just says in what scope the event will work).

Comment: @Plynx, i already did it. I substitute document with the id container of my link. thank you !

Comment: In my case I had to use the `each()` function, since using the a class selector `.class a` was not cutting it. It was for something very simple, but I think I'll try even delegation the next time.