# Jquery just work for first time

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

Hi guys i writes a code to approve or reject my options with JQuery and Smarty but i have some problems.
for example in first time when i approve one option its work perfectly but in second times when i want to approve or reject an other one there is nothing to happen.
no errors no reaction !!
its just work for first action !! why?

JS:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('#inreq_approve').click(function() {
    var frID = $(this).attr('f_inreq_id');
    var meID = $(this).attr('f_me_id');

    $.get('./_api.php', {
        mod: 'inreq_approve',
        key: frID,
        key2: meID,
    }, function(data) {
        if( data == '1'){
             alert('item was approved.');
             $("#inreq_"+frID).fadeOut(1000);
        }else if (data = '2'){
             alert('item wasnt approved.');
        }else {
             alert('error.');
        }
    });
    return false;
  });


  $('#inreq_reject').click(function() {
    var frID = $(this).attr('f_inreq_id');
    var meID = $(this).attr('f_me_id');

    $.get('./_api.php', {
        mod: 'inreq_reject',
        key: frID,
        key2: meID,
    }, function(data) {
        if( data == '1'){
             alert('item was rejected.');
             $("#inreq_"+frID).fadeOut(1000);
        }else if (data = '2'){
             alert('item wasnt rejected.');
        }else {
             alert('error.');
        }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
{foreach $friends_inc as $fi}   
<div id="inreq_{$fi.f_m_id}">
    <div class="name">
        <a>{$fi.f_m_name}</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
        <a href="#" class="tooltip-success" title="Approve">
            <i id="inreq_approve" f_inreq_id="{$fi.f_m_id}" f_me_id="{$smarty.session.uid}"></i>
        </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="tooltip-warning" title="Reject">
                <i id="inreq_reject" f_inreq_id="{$fi.f_m_id}" f_me_id="{$smarty.session.uid}"></i>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
{/foreach}
```

_api.php:

```
Switch ($mod) {

    Case $mod == "inreq_approve":

        $result = $df->sql_query('.....');
        $row = $df->sql_fetchrow($result);

        if (!empty($row)) {
            .....
               echo "1";
            } else {
                echo "2";
            }
        $df->sql_close();   
        break;

    Case $mod == "inreq_reject":

        $result = $df->sql_query('....');
        $row = $df->sql_fetchrow($result);

        if (!empty($row)) {
            .....
                echo "1";
            } else {
                echo "2";
            }
        $df->sql_close();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a runnable example?

Comment: i am working in local and my project not completed yet :(

Comment: http://output.jsbin.com/mamiwilugi

Comment: MY PROBLEM WAS RESOLVED. thanks to all. here is :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762859/jquery-click-bind-doesnt-work-second-time

Answer (score 0):

try to encapsulate your actions in functions and call inside it, like this:

```
var aprove = function(element) {
    $(element).click(function() {
         // your code
         $.get(url, function(data) {
              // your code
              aprove(element);
        });
    });
};
aprove(element);
```

Comment: i am trying with your way but same problem